# Error when moving a file

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML web form where users can upload multiple files. I am having trouble with moving the files though.

HTML:

My HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="save.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000"/>
    <input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Save.php:

```
<?php
    foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $file) {
    $target= UPLOADPATH . $file;
    move_uploaded_file($file, $target)
        or die('error with moving the file');
    $file= time() . $_FILES['uploads']['name'];
            echo $file;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if you have writing permissions on destination path?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name']` instead of `$_FILES['uploads']['name']` for moving the file. `name` is the original file name but `tmp_name` is the current uploaded file path.